# TFS Branching and Merging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm working on a project and I'm using TFS as a source control, i was thinking of using TFS branching,

as now i reached the current situation:

1. I have released a beta version of the project.
2. I want to have
       a team who do refactoring on the design and code.
3. I wanna have a
       different team who would add fixes and resolving small issues and
       maybe add tiny features to the beta version.

I think the refactoring is going to make a lot of changes to the project, probably adding new class projects, and making big changes to code, so i`m kinda thinking merging would be a big issue.

I don't know which scenario i should use, i read some about branching [Here](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/), and I`m kinda hesitate  to use it, what do you guys think ? what would you use for this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think merging would be any issue. You can find some branches examples [here](http://intovsts.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/techdays2010_branchingandmergingwithtfs2010.pdf)